# How do I use php or JavaScript to make a person be redirected to my mobile site if they are on a mobile?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mobile

I have a mobile site but I need a script to redirect a user to it if they are on a mobile device.

Comment: you don't. your site is your mobile site

Comment: You don't need JS to do this - check out my answer for an example of a PHP solution. It's different to what you were thinking, but quicker and cleaner, and also doesn't depend on JS etc. CSS solutions are valid, but hard to reverse implement on an existing site.

Comment: @raynos, up to a point, but depends on the objectives of the site.

Comment: Seperate mobile sites are bad design.

Comment: bad design is bad design, what's your point.

Comment: Aside: What's up with the uncommented downvote spray on these answers?

Comment: no idea, it's pretty hilarious

Comment: feel free to reset with some upvotes! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do it, but detecting the screen size is a good way to do that. Note that the screen width is independent of the browser window size.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
  document.location = "mobile.html";
}
//-->
</script>
```

You can also match specific devices like the iPhone or iPod by the [User Agent string](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/).

```
<script language=javascript>
<!--
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
   location.replace("http://url-to-send-them/iphone.html");
}
-->
</script>
```

**Important Caveat**

While this works, it's also *very* annoying to get redirected to the mobile site's front page when you're trying to visit a particular page. For example, when you follow a link from Facebook trying to access an article, if the site redirects you to the front page of the mobile version of the site, it's infuriating and very unhelpful! Chances are, they'll never try hard enough to find the content.

paulsm4 is correct that using CSS to serve a mobile layout for your site at the same URL instead of redirecting is a much more desirable solution. However if that's not an option, the next best thing is to redirect to the matching URL for the mobile version of the site.

For example, if you just have a different subdomain for your mobile site, then you can use Javascript to redirect to the correct page of the mobile version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Full URL:   http://example.com/articles/1
// Mobile URL: http://mobile.example.com/articles/1
if (screen.width <= 699) {
  // Redirect to the same page on the mobile site
  document.location.host = "mobile." + document.location.host;
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think screen width is a sensible solution. UA sniffing is not perfect, but if you absolutely have to do this kind of filtering, forcing a user to load a mobile site with a JS redirect because their window is an arbitrary size is not going to cut it. What happens if a user has reduced their window to load a site, then maximises it afterwards? Are you going to detect the resize event, and force a reload..?

Comment: I said this earlier, but I'll reiterate - "Note that the screen width is independent of the browser window size." You can test it by making your browser window small and calling screen.width in a javascript console. You'll still see your actual screen (resolution) width.

Answer (score 0):

You have to detect the browser first. Here's a page containing info about browser detection using javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp
If the detected browser was one of the mobile browsers, then you redirect them to another page.
Here's a very useful page about this subject: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html
also contains php code for browser detection

Answer (score -1):

Your first line of defense should be to use CSS:

- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/return-of-the-mobile-stylesheet
- http://perishablepress.com/the-5-minute-css-mobile-makeover/

Short of that, here's some Javascript that can do a redirect for you:

- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/

  `<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    if (screen.width <= 699) {
    document.location = "mobile.html";
    }
    //-->
  </script>`

Comment: @danp what part of `document.location = uri` is not a redirect ?

Comment: your user went to your site. they don't want to have to load a full desktop site then get bounced onto a mobile site (including all associated resource loading in the worst case scenario) when you can do http user agent filtering.. server side.

Comment: it's inefficient. The main reason to redirect to mobile is a mobile UI. The secondary reason is loading speeds

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to do this with JS - **the browser actually sends the agent string to PHP before anything is sent back to the browser in the HTTP headers**. Have a look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and you'll see what I mean.

CodeIgniter has a [user agent class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/user_agent.html) that can help with this kind of behaviour. The source for it is [here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/User_agent.php) and the resource file it uses with browser agent strings is [here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/user_agents.php).

Comment: There is no reliable way to map between userAgent and "user wants a mobile friendly interface"

Comment: Maybe, but it's about the best way to do it. As long as the user has the option to always go back to a desktop site if they want, I'm ok with this, and this is how I would tackle the problem.

Comment: Responsive / mobile first web design handles the entire problem more elegantly.

Comment: Server side filtering (if you really, really have to use UA sniffing) is the most unobtrusive way to do it, coupled with a link back to the full site for when UA sniffing gets it wrong. The user should be presented with an interface appropriate for their device. 

Media queries are great if you can factor in all the various problems and incompatibilities (of which there are many), but it's often impractical to do this on an existing codebase.

Comment: that's a really good point. In cost effective terms it's far easier to build a mobile version from scratch then refactor an existing website to be responsive.